# Java Affinity Lock

Tags: java, affinity

I have a newbie question, so I started looking at Java Affinity library and I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    AffinityLock l = AffinityLock.acquireLock(5);
    Thread.currentThread().setName("Testing");
    System.out.println("\nThe assignment of CPUs is\n" + AffinityLock.dumpLocks());
    while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){

    }
}
```

and I have output:

```
The assignment of CPUs is
0: General use CPU
1: Reserved for this application
2: Reserved for this application
3: Reserved for this application
4: Reserved for this application
5: Thread[Testing,5,main] alive=true
...
```

But if I go ps -alF, I can see the process is not running on PSR 5. Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks a lot!!
- Mag

Answer (score 0):

A thread could be executed on different cores. Please read this fascinating [discussion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/349972/how-does-a-single-thread-run-on-multiple-cores?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

In this particular case you can stop the debugger in the method `net.openhft.affinity.LockInventory.set(CpuLayout cpuLayout)` and do some steps to find out what happens during initialization of `logicalCoreLocks` array.

It looks like the dumped data was actual only at the moment of initialization, but it's not when being printed to the console.